# Magento set Current Timezone

Tags: magento-1.9, timezone

My store is from Chile

I'll set timezone America/Santiago from the backend.
When I place the order, it gets the wrong time.
I created one script and write below code.

```
  <?php require 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Tt returns 2018-09-07 11:30:43
but the current time in Chile is 2018-09-07 10:30:43
Can anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: check your server timezone

Comment: how can i check my server time?

Comment: write a php script and and echo date function

Comment: it returns the same

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if still not solve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code :

```
<?php 
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('America/Santiago'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: when order is place it take wrong time

Comment: so i want to set tizone globally and when i use  Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d H:i:s')

than it return right time